# the import org.apache.synapse cannot be resolved

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I just downloaded the latest version of WSO2 Dev Studio - Eclipse Luna v3.8. After upgrading my mediator projects all getting the same error "the import org.apache.synapse cannot be resolved" though I've tried several way such as Clean project.

Also, if I choose to Import an existing Maven project, it takes quite long to load Maven dependencies.

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a build path issue, As a solution we can do following.

1. delete the .classpath file(s) before importing to developerstudio-380
2. Import the project.
3. Then convert the project to a maven project ( right click on project -> configure ->Convert to Maven project)
4. Update project ( right click on project -> Maven -> Update project), this step will download the dependencies and resolve the build path issues.